# can you solve this?

Tags: command-line, grep

if you have a puzzle and you want to solve it with computer...

- **6 characters**
- the available characters is "NQAECFCYCPHY"

what is the possible right words can you get?
I tried to solve it with grep and an English wordlist

```
grep -E --text "^([NnQqAaEeCcFfCcYyCcPpHhYy]{6})$" wordsEn.txt > words-.txt
```

but i found "papaya" on the output and i don't want double-p or double-a maybe Double-c

i don't if it's lower or upper case

Comment: There is a thing with conditional regexes, but that would be complicated. I'd rather go for Python. It's mightier than Bash or grep for such complicated String processing.

Comment: However, I don't see any Ubuntu relation here. If it's just a programming question, you should better move over to [so]. That does not apply if you have a special reason to use Ubuntu-specific tools like `grep`. But if that's the case, please explicitly state and explain it.

Comment: @ByteCommander `grep` is no more Ubuntu-specific than `python`. Both are tools that are commonly available (and installed by default) on Ubuntu systems. Neither of them is in any way "Ubuntu-specific".

Comment: @terdon Isn't `grep` at least a *nix specific tool? Well, if it isn't it should be closed as off-topic anyway. And my recommendation to use Python instead of grep was not related to that...

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify your requirements. Should no letter be repeated? Should some be repeated but not others?

Comment: @ByteCommander *nix specific perhaps (it isn't, actually, but close enough), Ubuntu-specific certainly not! As you know, scripting questions are welcome here, the OP is even using `grep`. I don't see what would make this off topic. Unclear, yes, but off topic?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Python code for you, but I do not have the Python at hand to test, so this is only a sketch. I assume the dictionary is 1 word per line.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
letters_source = list("NQAwhatever")
word_list = open("/words/txt")
for word in word_list:
    letters = list(letters_source)
    try:
        for l in word:
            letters.remove(l)    
        print (word)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```